# App indexing for apps with a single main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-app-indexing

Our android app has a single main activity. All subsequent screens have been implemented as fragments.

We are trying to implement app indexing using the google developers guide. However, because there is a single main activity, only the home screen is being indexed. We also tried to handle the incoming intents at a fragment level rather than the activity level, but it still doesn't work.

Has anyone successfully implemented app indexing for apps with multiple fragments instead of multiple activities? Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what "developers guide" are you referring to?

Comment: The guide referred to is probably this one: https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/publish

Answer (score 2):

This should work. Here's how I imagine your app working:

1. Your manifest has an intent filter which sends deep links to your MainActivity.
2. The `MainActivity` captures intents when the activity starts or resumes.
3. If the intent that started MainActivity is a `VIEW_ACTION` then the deep link is parsed from the data payload and a fragment is rendered with the content for that deep link.
4. In the `onStart()` method for you fragment, you call the App Indexing API to register the `start()` of the view.
5. When the user navigates away from that page in your app, a different fragment gets shown.
6. In the `onStop()` method for your deep-linked fragment, make sure that you call the App Indexing API to register the `end()` of the view.

Note that those last few steps require that the fragment knows the original deep link URI that was passed into the `MainActivity` so you'll need to make sure that the fragment has a reference back to that URI.